# Issue with turning a test file into a package with __init__.py

Tags: python, django

I am following along with this tutorial:

http://www.marinamele.com/taskbuster-django-tutorial/create-home-page-with-tdd-staticfiles-templates-settings

When I run:

```
(tb_test)metersk:functional_tests metersky$ python test_all_users.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 2.313s

OK
```

The test works as it should.  The test being :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest


class NewVisitorTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_it_worked(self):
        self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000')
        self.assertIn('Welcome to Django', self.browser.title)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(warnings='ignore')
```

However, when I follow the step to add a blank `__init__.py` file to the directory, and I run the test like so: `python manage.py test functional_tests`

I get a the following failure:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/metersky/code/taskbuster_project/taskbuster/settings/base.py", line 20, in get_env_variable
    return os.environ[var_name]
  File "/Users/metersky/.virtualenvs/tb_test/bin/../lib/python3.4/os.py", line 633, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'


  File "/Users/metersky/code/taskbuster_project/taskbuster/settings/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .base import *
  File "/Users/metersky/code/taskbuster_project/taskbuster/settings/base.py", line 31, in <module>
    SECRET_KEY = get_env_variable('SECRET_KEY')
  File "/Users/metersky/code/taskbuster_project/taskbuster/settings/base.py", line 23, in get_env_variable
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: set the SECRET_KEY environment variable
```

I don't quite understand how calling the test script differently from the command line would prevent the program from finding the secret key environment variable.  It clearly works when I call the script on its own.

Folder structure:

```
├── TaskBuster.sublime-project
├── TaskBuster.sublime-workspace
├── db.sqlite3
├── functional_tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test_all_users.py
├── manage.py
├── requirements
│   ├── base.txt
│   ├── development.txt
│   ├── production.txt
│   └── testing.txt
└── taskbuster
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── settings.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── urls.cpython-34.pyc
    │   └── wsgi.cpython-34.pyc
    ├── db.sqlite3
    ├── settings
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── base.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   └── development.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── base.py
    │   ├── development.py
    │   ├── production.py
    │   ├── staging.py
    │   └── testing.py
    ├── static
    │   ├── css
    │   │   ├── bootstrap-theme.css
    │   │   ├── bootstrap-theme.css.map
    │   │   ├── bootstrap-theme.min.css
    │   │   ├── bootstrap.css
    │   │   ├── bootstrap.css.map
    │   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
    │   │   └── main.css
    │   ├── favicon.ico
    │   ├── fonts
    │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
    │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
    │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
    │   │   └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
    │   ├── img
    │   └── js
    │       ├── main.js
    │       └── vendor
    │           ├── bootstrap.js
    │           ├── bootstrap.min.js
    │           ├── jquery-1.11.2.min.js
    │           ├── modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js
    │           └── npm.js
    ├── templates
    │   ├── 404.html
    │   ├── base.html
    │   ├── humans.txt
    │   └── robots.txt
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

Comment: Can you post your folder structure please?

Comment: Also, not that I think it's related, but it's `__init__.py`, not `__init.py__`. Not sure if that's a typo or the actual file you created.

Comment: Typo, fixing now and folder structure added.

Comment: And you're in the `tb_test` virtualenv when you are running `./manage.py test functional_tests`?

Comment: @dursk yes i am, with tb_dev running the server in a different terminal

Comment: @dursk the way the secret key was kind off weird to me, but the way i set it is here: http://www.marinamele.com/taskbuster-django-tutorial/settings-different-environments-version-control

Comment: Under the `tb_test` env what is the output at the terminal if you type `$SECRET_KEY`?

Comment: @dursk `echo $SECRET_KEY` gives me the key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92676/discussion-between-dursk-and-meter).